# How to make an app appear in games sections of windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have made a game(simple one, does not use xna).

I want that when installed it should appear in the games (xbox) section in windows phone 7/8.
(I mean on the phone and not marketplace)

How to do this?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: in visual studio 2012, in the appmanifest there is nothing like genre.
So, the answer given in the possible duplicate didn't help

Comment: This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) seems to indicate otherwise (search the page for `apps.normal`). Maybe the attribute is missing in your manifest, and the default value is `apps.normal`. Try adding the attribute and setting it to `apps.games` (also try `apps.game` since that article mentions both).