# Universal Win8.1 app genre setting

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, monogame

I'm working to create a MonoGame game as a Win8.1 universal app.

As I remember from my previous WinPhone 8 / WinPhone 8.1 Silverlight apps, in order for the OS to understand that an app is a game and should be shown in the Games Hub (or Xbox section or however MS decides to call it), we had to edit the WMAppManifest.xml file and add in the App node a Genre attribute with the value "apps.games", as can be seen in SO questions like:

[How to make an app appear in games (xbox) section of wp 7/8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291720/how-to-make-an-app-appear-in-games-xbox-section-of-wp-7-8/15291953#15291953)

[How to make an app appear in games sections of windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303984/how-to-make-an-app-appear-in-games-sections-of-windows-phone?lq=1)

However, WMAppManifest.xml is not used in WP8.1 non-Silverlight apps. It has been more or less replaced by Package.appxmanfest, that does not accept the Genre attribute.

So, the question is: How can we declare to the OS that our app is game in Universal (w8.1/wp8.1) apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the app categories on the dashboard when you upload your app:

```
Submissions->App Properites->Category and Subcategory
```

The Category would be Games. The Subcategory the genre.

See the [Enter app properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt148533.aspx) docs and the [Category and subcategory table](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=528665) for more details.

Comment: So, that would mean that in my dev device, all deployed (by VS) applications are considered as "apps" and not as "games", right? Is there any specific mention of the Genre attribute being obsolete?